# How do I view my iCloud Photo Stream online?

Tags: ios, icloud, photos.app, photo-stream

I set up iCloud when I installed iOS 5 on my iPhone and was excited about Photo Stream. I logged into icloud.com and found there are no photos. What gives? I was hoping that this would end the need to selectively pull photos off my phone, then upload, then share. But it looks like you can only sync between iOS devices and Lion (which I don't have). Is there a web interface or some other way to see these photos?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> **Update:** Apple now allows you to share your Photo Stream with others. More info on the official Photo Stream page [here](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/photo-stream.html)

At the moment no. The only way to access your stream is from a Lion Machine using either iPhoto or Aperture, or from another iOS 5.0 device with Photo Stream enabled.

I am not entirely sure if Apple is going to allow a sharing portal, however at the moment I take the images I want to share and upload them to Flickr through iPhoto once they are in my Photo Stream.

I suspect they currently use Photo Stream as a personal backup and sharing solution between devices, and not global sharing.

Comment: There's also easy syncing with Windows PCs - see [other answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28489/how-do-i-view-my-icloud-photo-stream-online/28500#28500)

Comment: If you go to iCloud.com now, they should appear on there under Photos assuming you have iCloud Photo Library (beta) turned on in iOS 8

Answer (score 7):

There is also already a mechanism to sync PhotoStream photos to Windows PCs.

See [the PC instructions on 'How to set up iCloud'](http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html).

I've used this and it works well. It adds a new folder to your PC, wherever your pictures are currently stored (e.g. the Pictures library, if on Windows 7).

Once they've been synced to the PC, you can just upload them using whatever software you'd normally use...

Answer (score 2):

It's not so clear from the other answers but it is now possible to enable the creation of [**publicly accessible website**](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12068) of selected photos from selected photo stream. Basically you need to enable (Settings -> Photos & Camera) 'Shared Photo Streams' on your iOS device - You don't need to enable My PhotoStream for this to work. Then from the Photos app you can create a shared photo stream from a bunch of photos for which you can enable (Photos app -> Shared tab -> People tab) 'Public Website'. This link can be shared and also has options for adding subscribers who can post (in iOS8).

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the pictures in the photostream in your phone and click on the save button: it will save all those pictures in the Camera Roll, and next time when you connect phone with PC, you can see all of them in iPhone drive in My Computer.

Comment: This should probably be a comment since it doesn't answer the question.