# Is there a web viewer for photos stored on iCloud?

Tags: photo-stream, icloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I view my iCloud Photo Stream online?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28489/how-do-i-view-my-icloud-photo-stream-online)

I am new to iCloud. When I open [iCloud.com](http://www.icloud.com) and login with my Apple ID, I couldn't find my photos there. Is it possible to view photos on iCloud.com itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment. To view your [Photo Stream](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/photo-stream.html) you need to access it on an Apple device (Mac, iOS or Apple TV) that's signed in with your iCloud ID. iCloud.com doesn't offer any functionality to view the Photo Stream, and it seems unlikely to any time soon.

Comment: I accessed photostream even on my Windows PC too... but i am unable to see my pictures there. so, is there any way to view photos on icloud.com

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can't view it on the iCloud site. To access it from a Windows PC, read [Apple's instructions](http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use iPhoto to see this PhotoStream.
You can activate it in the left sidebar or in the your Mac preferences under 'iCloud'.

That's how I see my photos in the iCloud on my Mac. Unfortunately, it's limited to the last 30 days, so not all your iCloud photos will appear in this list. But it's rather easy to create different albums from your PhotoStream to you Mac!

Comment: if we can see on icloud.com then whereever we go, we can see it through web without having photostream or iphoto